# how to create filtered image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

For the given images, create images that have been filtered and contain frequencies that are (a) less than 4 cpd (b) greater than 8 cpd and (c) between 4 cpd and 8 cpd. Assume that the distance between the monitor and the potential subject is 60 cm.

[image: Face]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is it your homework?

Comment: yea it has been one of the question from my assingment. and i am stuck in that.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also see [Stackoverflow policy on Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) - specifically, note the points about "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "Ask about specific problems with your *existing* implementation." Many of us are more than happy to try and help with homework questions, but you need to show some effort on your part first. I look forward to an expanded version of your question, and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I will leave the actual answer to you but here is a hint: filtering an image in spatial domain is equivalent of  multiplying its fourier version by a mask. 
For low pass filtering, mask may be circular disk. For high pass filtering, mask is circular hole. For band pass filtering, mask is a circular donut.

Comment: well tanx for the hint. but i think it will be big help if i get the matlab codes for this.